# Integração Cielo Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Uso Woocommerce e estou tentando implementar o pagamento através da Cielo usando o plugin do Gabriel Reguly.

https://github.com/greguly/cielo-woocommerce/

Porém, quando estou na página de checkout e seleciono a opção da cielo não aparece nenhuma opção de cartão nem parcelamento. Quando clico em Finalizar Compra, é retornado um JSON de erro, porém não consigo identificar de onde vem esse JSON.

```
{"result":"failure","messages":"","refresh":"false","reload":"false"}
```

Não consigo identificar se o erro é do Woocommerce ou do Plugin.

Estou usando a versão 3.0.0 do plugin. E Wordpress 3.9.1.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, a versão 3.0.0 não esta pronta ainda, esta em desenvolvimento e vai demorar alguns dias ainda para ficar pronta.
Se quer usar o plugin, baixe a versão de produção que esta disponível em http://wordpress.org/plugins/cielo-woocommerce/

Comment: Provavelmente, a *Development Version* no `trunk`: http://wordpress.org/plugins/cielo-woocommerce/developers/

Comment: @brasofilo o que esta no `trunk` é a versão 2.0.10. Estamos mantendo o desenvolvimento apenas pelo Github, justamente que assim é mais simples para outras pessoas contribuem com o código e o no WordPress.org usamos apenas para servir as versões.

Comment: Ah, sorry, me confundi ao ler aqui "versão de produção" :)

Comment: Versão 3.0.0 já esta disponível para produção em http://wordpress.org/plugins/cielo-woocommerce/